# How can I capture Arrows Keys in jQuery Datables.net

Tags: jquery, events, datatables, key

I wish to capture Arrow up/down key in jQuery Datables.net 
The code bellow:

```
const table = $('#table').DataTable({
    keys: true
})

table.on('key', function (e, datatable, key, cell, originalEvent) {
       alert(key)
})
```

In most cases are true except arrows key
How can I capture arrows key in jQuery Datables.net

https://datatables.net/

Comment: From the official jquery website : https://api.jquery.com/keyup/

Answer (score 0):

From the official jquery website : api.jquery.com/keyup

```
$( "#target" ).keyup(function() {
     alert( "Handler for .keyup() called." );
});
```